# IE11 gives SCRIPT1002 error when defining class in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have some trouble with IE11 and a static javascript class I wrote.

The error I get is:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>   rgmui.box.js (6,1)

Which points to:

```
// ===========================================
// RGMUI BOX
// Static class

class RgMuiBox {
^
```

So I'm guessing I'm defining this class in the wrong way? What's the correct way of doing this?

I found a post on SO that seems to point out that the issue is ES5 vs ES6 - and I figure IE11 doesn't support ES6?

Just to be complete, this is what I have (simplified):

```
class RgMuiBox {
    static method1() {
    // .. code ..
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: According [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), classes are not recognized by IE11.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hate to reopen such an old issue, but it still shows up high in the results, so I'll add what I found out:

To reiterate what @Mikey and @REJH said, classes are not recognized by IE11.

That said, tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) will allow you to translate classes into something that will run on IE11.

Comment: Thank you saved my day. This works 100%. I just converted my classes into Babel's content and resaved again. It works now in all Browsers even Safari.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to use Babel in the development environment (ng serve)

Answer (score 10):

@Mikey is right. IE11 does not recognize this syntax for classes because ES6 spec:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

```
class RgMuiBox {
    static method1() {
    // .. code ..
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure if the following is the correct way to define a static class but it works:

```
var RgMuiBox = {};
  RgMuiBox.method = function() {
    // ....
  }
```

Just putting it out here so this question has some sort of an answer that might help people get going. If there are alternatives to the above I like to hear about those!

Answer (score 2):

Static class Example

```
var _createClass = (function () {
    function defineProperties(target, props) {
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var descriptor = props[i];
            descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
            descriptor.configurable = true;
            if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
            Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
        }
    }
    return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
        if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
        if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
        return Constructor;
    };
})();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
}

var StaticClass = (function () {
    function StaticClass() {
        _classCallCheck(this, StaticClass);
    }

    _createClass(StaticClass, null, [{
        key: "method1",
        value: function method1() {
            // .. code ..
        }
    }]);

    return StaticClass;
 })();
```