# IE doesn't recognise Javascript Class and breaks

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I wrote some Javascript code that works perfectly in all major browsers. Of course I made sure that none of this would be executed by Internet Explorer by creating a function that figures out what browser the user is using.

Here's the problem however: Even if I told IE not to execute the code, the browser still reads all of my Javascript and since it finds something it doesn't recognise it stops running any other Javascript.

The only thing I could think of doing was creating a function that would return if the user is using IE, but that doesn't seem to work since I think the problem comes from IE initially parsing my script and not being able to understand modern JS syntax.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
  class Section {
    constructor(dom, startPosition, endPosition, backgroundPosition) {
      this.dom = dom;
      this.startPosition = startPosition;
      this.endPosition = endPosition;
      this.backgroundPosition = backgroundPosition;
    }
  }


function isIE() {
  ua = navigator.userAgent;
  /* MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones*/
  var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

  return is_ie;
}

let sections = [];
function sectionParallax() {
  if (!isIE()) {
    sections.push( new Section("test", 123, 123, 123))
  }
}
```

IE's console reports:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

On `class Section`.

I'm completely out of ideas on what to do here. How do I make sure IE doesn't load this part of the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194202/ie11-gives-script1002-error-when-defining-class-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript classes and constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) not support IE browser, so, in the IE browser, it will show the "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" error.

You could modify your code as below:

```
    var Section = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Section(dom, startPosition, endPosition, backgroundPosition) {
            this.dom = dom;
            this.startPosition = startPosition;
            this.endPosition = endPosition;
            this.backgroundPosition = backgroundPosition;
        }
        return Section;
    }());
    function isIE() {
        ua = navigator.userAgent;
        /* MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones*/
        var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
        return is_ie;
    }
    var sections = [];
    function sectionParallax() {
        if (!isIE()) {
            /*If not using IE browser.  */
            var newsection = new Section("test", 123, 123, 123);
            sections.push(newsection);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The JS parser has to parse the JavaScript you tell it to load, even if it is a function that never executes.

If you want to stop IE from loading it, then *don't load the `<script>` which contains it*. This means you need to dynamically add the `<script>` if the browser does support the feature.

If you need to support IE, then don't deliver JS to the browser that uses syntax IE doesn't recognise. Consider using a tool like Babel to transpile it to an older version of JavaScript which IE does support.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `IE` before loading the script with a [Conditional Comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) :

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Although the first line should be `<!--[if !IE]>-->`, your way didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually on closer inspection this doesn't seem to work, IE still loads all of the script. Damn

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems to work for IE10 and previous versions, and nothing above.